# Convert Null to text on numeric field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that LEFT joins 4 different tables. There will always be a match in one of these tables but we don't know which one. When the query is executed there are some fields producing NULL values. These are float fields but I was wondering if there is a way to change the Null to some kind of indicator such as "No Coverage"?

I have attempted something simple such as:

```
ISNULL(acccoverage, 'No Coverage') AS acccoverage
```

However when I run this I get the following error message:

```
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

I'm sure its something simple but I have tried CONVERT and CAST but with no joy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I'm sure its something simple but I have tried CONVERT and CAST but with no joy."* Then show us that attempt. However mixing data types in a column is a bad idea; if you must display `'No Coverage'` when the value is `NULL`, you're better off defining that in the presentation layer, not the RDBMS.

Comment: Actually `mixing data types in a column` is impossible, unless you don't convert them all to some character type. Sure this is job for presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `COALESCE()`.  It is the standard function.  Then convert the number to a string:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), acccoverage), 'No Coverage')
```

You can do the same thing with `ISNULL()`.